# Enable and disable com add-ins

Tags: excel, excel-addins

how to enable / disable using vba excel on (com add-ins) excel ?

[image]

Comment: Please Google before posting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565694/enable-com-addins-in-excel-through-vba  If you *have* already googled, please explain what you tried, and what problem(s) you had when trying, so folks don't waste time suggesting things you already looked at.

Comment: okay thanks for the info very helpful. sorry maybe the keywords I am looking for are not specific enough. but thanks again

Comment: but do not understand, 
Public Sub Connect_COM_AddIn(Name As String)
    Application.COMAddIns(Name).Connect = True
End Sub

Public Sub Disconnect_COM_AddIn(Name As String)
    Application.COMAddIns(Name).Connect = False
End Sub

im try error

Comment: Please [edit] that code into your question, thanks.